# NSInternalInconsistencyException when trying to insert row in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a food diary in my app that should be able to insert a row with information of the food the user has inputed. Everytime I try I get this error: "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 3 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'"

This is the ViewController code that performs the insert.

```
class FoodDiary: UITableViewController, AddRowDelegate {


var tableData = [[String: Any]]() //Datasource

    func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String, section: Int) {

    let getName = ["name":name, "calories":calories] as [String: Any]
    tableData.append(getName)
   let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tableData.count + 1, section: section)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


    calsforToday.text = calories


    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is my other ViewController that shows when the user is inputting the data with the protocol method.

```
    protocol AddRowDelegate {
func didAddRow(name : String, calories : String, section : Int)
 }




 class PopupVC: UIViewController {

var delegate: AddRowDelegate?
var section: Int?

@IBOutlet weak var foodTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopup2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopUp: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inputFood: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inputCals: UITextField!

@IBAction func saveToDiary(_ sender: Any) {


    delegate?.didAddRow(name: inputFood.text!, calories: inputCals.text!, section: section!)


    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "diaryEntry" {
        if let selectedIndexPath = 
  tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.first{
        let popVC = segue.destination as! PopupVC
            popVC.delegate = self


            if selectedIndexPath == 0 {
                let label = "Add Breakfast"
                popVC.foodLabel = label
                popVC.section = 0
```

Pics of both VC's.

[image: FoodDiary]

[image: PopUpVC]

How can I get the row to insert with the information the user inputs?

Comment: `tableData.count + 1` should be `tableData.count - 1`

Comment: Doesn't work. Shows this: "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'" @dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan said in a comment, you need `tableData.count - 1` for your new index path row.

For example, if there are two elements in your array (count = 2) then you have rows 0 and 1 (i.e. count-1 is the last row).

```
func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String, section: Int) {

    let getName = ["name":name, "calories":calories] as [String: Any]
    tableData.append(getName)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tableData.count-1, section: section)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

    calsforToday.text = calories
}
```

A couple of other points:

1. There is no need to reload the whole table since you have already inserted the new row.  Reloading will give an unwanted visual effect
2. I suggest that you create a struct for your data model rather than using a dictionary
3. You will need an array for each section.

```
struct FoodItem {
    var name: String
    var calories: String // This should probably be an Int
}

class FoodDiary: UITableViewController, AddRowDelegate {

    var tableData = Array(repeating: [FoodItem](), count: 3) 

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableData[section].count
    }

    func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String, section: Int) {

        let newItem = FoodItem(name:name, calories:calories)
        tableData[section].append(newItem)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tableData[section].count-1, section: section)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

        calsforToday.text = calories
    }

  //  Not shown; update your `cellForRow(at:)` to use the indexpath.section and row to get the required array and item. 
}
```

Comment: It still doesnt work. Now shows this: "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'"

Comment: Is your section number correct?  This error says that you didn't insert any rows, but you did.  I notice that the `numberOfRowsInSection` that you added as a comment to the other answer didn't do anything for different sections.  So you are inserting a new row in section 0, but because you seem to be using the same array for all sections, section 1 is also seeing a new row that it didn't; expect and you get an exception

Comment: I'm basically getting the section through my PrepareforSegueMethod. Like so:    if segue.identifier == "diaryEntry" {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.first{
            let popVC = segue.destination as! PopupVC
                popVC.delegate = self
                
                
                if selectedIndexPath == 0 {
                    let label = "Add Breakfast"
                    popVC.foodLabel = label
                    popVC.section = 0
I'm passing the section to my PopUpVC so it knows what section the row must be inserted in.

Comment: Yes, but in your tableview data source you have multiple sections but you are only using one array; you return the same array count for all sections.  Then in the delegate method you tell the tableview that you are inserting a new row in section 0, but because the same array is also used in section 1, the tableview sees an additional row in section 1 (numberOfRowsInSection returns 2) that it didn't expect because there was no `insertRow()` for row 1 in section 1.

Comment: ahhhh! that makes total sense!!!! How can I make different arrays for different sections

Comment: You can use a nested array; e.g. `var tableData = Array(repeating: [[String:AnyObject]](), count: 4)` so you have an array of arrays of dictionaries (but seriously, create a struct and put that in your array); one array of dictionaries for each section.

Comment: Im following you, it makes sense why it was crashing. Is there anyway you can write a sample of properly creating a struct and using that as the datasource? I'm still a bit new to iOS Development. You're a huge help!!! Thank you! This bug has been bothering me for days!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143447/discussion-between-paulw11-and-thelegendary3).