# I get the crash on return statement in numberOfRowsInSection of UITableView after update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is my code by which I get the data from web service in pages of 10 record each:

```
func callService() {
    ProfileApiStore.shared.requestToGetProfile(loggedInUserId: UserStore.shared.userId, userId:  UserStore.shared.userIdToViewProfile, limit: "10", page: String(self.pageNumber), completion: {(result) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.totalPages = result.totalPages!
        let newItems = result.userdata?.newPostData

        tableView.beingUpdates()
        for item in newItems {
            self.listData.append(item)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.listData!.count-1), section:0) // shouldn't this be just self.listData!.count as your adding a new row?
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    })
}
```

I get the error as:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 10 into section 0, but there are only 10 rows in section 0 after the update'

This crash occurs on numberOfRowsInSection at return statement:

```
if listData != nil{
    print("list count in numberOfRowsInSection\(listData?.count)")
    return (listData?.count)!
}
return 0
```

The Issue was due to following lines in which i tried to update scrollview height from tableview content in child view controller:

```
if (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController is UserPrfileControl){
            if (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).childControllerToUpdate == "userPost"{
                (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).commentViewHeight.constant = 0
                (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).burnedPostsHeight.constant = 0
                (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).userProfileViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSInternalInconsistencyException when trying to insert row in tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792435/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-when-trying-to-insert-row-in-tableview)

Comment: Please add what type is `listData`; Add `numberOfRows` method. As for your comment "shouldn't this be just self.listData!.c"... No. It is correctly as it is because you are first appending data to `listData`. So if you start with 10 you then first add the 11th item which means you are adding it in 10th index ergo `count-1 == 11-1 == 10`

Comment: Please paste *your actual code* - You have a typo `beingUpdates`, plus your `self.listData` is an optional in `numberOfRows` but not in the first code block and you don't unwrap `newItems`.  All of these errors mean you did not copy/paste your code.  The code shown here is correct and wouldn't produce the error shown.  Also, your `numberOfRows` can be reduced to a single line `return self.listData?.count ?? 0`

Comment: Thank you all, the probem I was facing due to the following lines in which I tried to update the ScrollView height according to tableview in child controller:

Comment: Please guide me how can I update the scrollview height from the content size of tableview in child view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest, that when you execute `callService()` for the second time, your table view already has 10 rows and you try to add new records. But UITable view doesn't call `numberOfRowsInSection` at the moment and doesn't know the new number of items in `listData`. So you need to say to UITable that the number of items has changed, just call `UITableView.reloadData()` function when you added new items in `listData`.

```
func callService() {
    ProfileApiStore.shared.requestToGetProfile(loggedInUserId: UserStore.shared.userId, userId:  UserStore.shared.userIdToViewProfile, limit: "10", page: String(self.pageNumber), completion: {(result) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.totalPages = result.totalPages!
        let newItems = result.userdata?.newPostData

        for item in newItems {
            self.listData.append(item)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```